# How to correctly render html entities assigned to variables in React?

Tags: reactjs, html-entities

In React, the code below correctly renders a double quotation mark (") to the page:

```
export default Character() {
  return (
    <p>&quot;</p> // renders as the symbol "
  )
}
```

However, if the HTML entity is assigned to a variable, that entity is displayed as a string:

```
export default Character() {

  const char = "&quot;"

  return (
    <p>{char}</p> // renders as a the string "&quot;"
  )
}
```

Could anyone please explain to me why the two implementations cause different behaviors?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Strings are not treated the same as JSX in React. Those two are not identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is considered as HTML content and processed by HTML before rendering.

```html
<p>&quot;</p>
```

When you set it using a string reference(in React) preprocessing of symbols in the string is ignored somehow.

```html
<p>{char}</p>
```

If you have a string with [HTML Symbols](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp), you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute in React to get rid of the issue.

```html
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: char }} />
```

To avoid XSS, sanitize the string using [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html).

1. Install the package

```
npm i sanitize-html
```

2. Simply use it like below

```
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';
...
...
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitizeHtml("your-text<script src=""></script>") }} />
```

Output will be => "your-text" by ignoring the `script` section.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-archimedes-slffn?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @S4muele, check this out !!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Apparently though, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` could expose my site to [cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#:~:text=cross%2Dsite%20scripting%20(XSS)%20attack.), so that wouldn't seem to be an ideal solution in my specific case..

Comment: you should sanitize your string before using it

Comment: If you're pretty confident `char` will only ever contain a single HTML entity and don't want to include a whole sanitization library, you could always do a lightweight sanity check, something like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: char.match(/&#?\w+;/)?.[0] ?? '' }}`. Or if you're 100% confident (e.g. the string is developer-supplied, not user-supplied), you could just skip sanitization altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<>fragment</>`

```
export default Character() {

  const char = <>&quot;</>

  return (
    <p>{char}</p>
  )
}
```